# Csom Powershell script to check Web Part Page and Wiki page

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

We are required to find out the number of wiki pages and web part pages present in a site pages library across all the webs in a big site collection, this needs to be determined in sharepoint online,is there any method in powershell csom by which this can be achieved?

any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance